# Reading a file with scanf and a do while loop

Tags: c, scanf, do-while

I'm reading a file with `scanf`. Each line is just one data field, so I have a a do while loop. Basically what I do is, read the first information for build the root (i'm using this for build a BST). But when gets inside the do while. Reads weird things. Read and create correct all data, but for each iteration for the loop, call twice times the same method for read a file and I don't what is happening now.

```
comp_node_ptr read_competitor_node(int id, FILE * competitor_filename){

   int scan_status;

   int feet;
   double inches;

   competitor_node * tmp_node;

   tmp_node = calloc(1, sizeof(tmp_node));

   scan_status = fscanf(competitor_filename, "%[^\n]\n", tmp_node -> name );

   if(scan_status == EOF){
      printf("End Of File. \n");
      free(tmp_node);
      return NULL;
   }

   tmp_node -> id = id;

   fscanf(competitor_filename, "%[^\n]\n", tmp_node -> addres );

   fscanf(competitor_filename, "%[^\n]\n", tmp_node -> phone_number );

   fscanf(competitor_filename, "%d %lf", &feet, &inches );
   tmp_node -> cucumber = convertToInches(feet, inches);

   fscanf(competitor_filename, "%d %lf", &feet, &inches );
   tmp_node ->carrot = convertToInches(feet, inches);

   fscanf(competitor_filename, "%d %lf", &feet, &inches );
   tmp_node -> bean = convertToInches(feet, inches);

   printNode(tmp_node);

   return tmp_node;

}

root = read_competitor_node(id, competitor_table_file);

do{
   id++;
   tmp_node = read_competitor_node(id, competitor_table_file);
   add_competitor(root, tmp_node);
}while(tmp_node != NULL);
```

And prints the following data:

```
Margaret Mouse     1 Southern 9565          1 ft -0.500000 in     2 ft -3.200001 in     1 ft -4.500000 in -134217728 ft 0.000000 in 
               2                     1 ft -4.500000 in     1 ft -4.500000 in     1 ft -4.500000 in     0 ft 0.000000 in 
Bert Hill      3 Central 2010          1 ft -7.200001 in     1 ft -8.200001 in     2 ft -11.700001 in 156587349 ft -4.000000 in 
               4         �   27263573 ft -4.000000 in 27263573 ft -4.000000 in 27263573 ft -4.000000 in     0 ft 0.000000 in 
Donald Duck     5 Marine 1234567          2 ft -0.400000 in     2 ft -4.500000 in     1 ft -6.200001 in 145402538 ft -8.000000 in 
               6         �   27263570 ft -8.000000 in 27263570 ft -8.000000 in 27263570 ft -8.000000 in -67108864 ft 0.000000 in 
End Of File.
```

2, 4 and 6 I don't know where that come. 1, 3 and 5 is the correct data from the file that i'm reading, but all the other where they come?

the struct data is the following:

```
typedef struct competitor_status {

int id;
char name[MAX_TEXT_LENGTH];
char addres[MAX_TEXT_LENGTH];
char phone_number[MAX_TEXT_LENGTH];
float cucumber;
float carrot;
float bean;

struct competitor_status * left; /* links to teams with more or same points */
struct competitor_status * right; /* links to teams with less points */

} competitor_node;

typedef competitor_node * comp_node_ptr;
```

Comment: why do you use `calloc` for initializing `tmp_node` if it is not an array? use instead `malloc`

Comment: for make sure that all the space allocated to that variable is set to zero, deleting previously whats there before

Comment: that output seem like a BufferOverFlow on your code, or bad pointer assignaments.

Comment: try using `malloc` and `memset` to check if error persist

Comment: added information about the structs and the pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code

```
competitor_node * tmp_node;
tmp_node = calloc(1, sizeof(tmp_node));
scan_status = fscanf(competitor_filename, "%[^\n]\n", tmp_node -> name );
```

the variable `*tmp_node` is a pointer to `competitor_node` and you allocate enough memory *only for a pointer* and not for one `competitor_node`.

Even when you correct this to

```
tmp_node = calloc(1, sizeof(*tmp_node));
```

the memory is initialised to `0` so the next line

```
scan_status = fscanf(competitor_filename, "%[^\n]\n", tmp_node -> name );
```

is passing a `NULL` pointer to `fscanf()`.

**EDIT** folowing OP posting `typedef struct competitor_status` the next lines are not relevant.

[ You must initialise this `struct` field too (and any other pointers in the `struct`) perhaps like this

```
tmp_node->name = malloc(MAXSTRINGLENGTH+1);
```

but there isn't enough detail to be more specific. ]

Comment: I added more information for the struct, and for the comp_node_ptr variable

Comment: thanks for your answer, but still having the same proble also with tmp_node = calloc(1, sizeof(*tmp_node));

Comment: @Jota_sk or is it `convertToInches()` or `add_competitor()` or `printNode()` you are having a problem with? None of which are shown. Please read the MCVE page! http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is not he printing the problem. The problem is that actually that node are created and inserted into the tree. As you can see the nodes with the id 2, 4 and 6 (id is the number just after the name) are nodes created and I don't know from where. the nodes 1, 3 and 5 are nodes with the correct data from the file.

Comment: solved the problems was from the functions previously mentioned. Yes I readed the MCVE page, that that help me to resolve the problem, i create a new project with a really basic function for test and I see the bug, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`tmp_node = calloc(1, sizeof(tmp_node));` should be `tmp_node = calloc(1, sizeof *tmp_node);`.

`tmpnode` is a pointer to a node (`sizeof tmp_node` should be 4 or 8), but you want to allocate memory for a node.

`sizeof *tmp_node` is the size of the struct `tmp_node` is pointing to.